# Is it possible to view my local website over wifi on other pc/mobile phone using server2go as my portable webserver?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, webserver

I tried to view my address on my mobile phone using Xampp and it worked perfectly. I connected my phone wifi to the pc hotspot, checked my pc ipv4 address using ipconfig on cmd and typed this address on my mobile phone browser address bar and it worked but didn't work with server2go since it has a special proxy address and port different from that of the pc (127.0.0.1:4001/website_name.php).

I want to know if server2go can be used for this same purpose and if so, how do I go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` is a special loopback address that refers to [`localhost`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost): the machine you are currently using.

You should be able to see a a web server on your PC from your phone, when the phone is connected to the same wifi network.  But you need to use your PC's private IP address, which is probably in a format similar to `192.168.xxx.xxx`. This should be the address you see when you run `ipconfig` on your PC.

You also need to use the correct port number.  From your question, it looks like Server2go is using port 4001.  So if your PC's IP address is `192.168.1.123`, you would point your phone's web browser at `http://192.168.1.123:4001/website_name.php`.